# VirtualHosts on Debian not working

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost

I have setup a local server with debian 6 squeeze. But I cannot get virtualhosts to work. I would like to setup multiple virtualhosts but I just started with one.

I disabled the default apache virtual host

```
a2dissite default
```

Setup the virtual host and directories
**/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.local**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@test.local
 ServerName test.local
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/test.local/public_html/
 ErrorLog /srv/www/test.local/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /srv/www/test.local/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I enabled the site

```
a2ensite test.local
```

Restarted server

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Added it to **/etc/hosts**

```
192.168.1.60 test.local
```

When I browse to test.local, I just get a server not found error. I have also cleared all cookies. It only works, if I just go to 192.168.1.60.

Also my apache2.conf in **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** has

```
Include ports.conf
```

ports.conf in **/etc/apache2/ports.conf** has

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
 # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
 # to <VirtualHost *:443>
 # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
 # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Server not found" implies a name resolution issue, which is backed up by it working correctly when using just the IP.

Keep in mind that a modification to the hosts file will only work for the local system - so you'll need to be browsing from the system that's had the modification made.

If you're doing that, I'd suspect that your modification to the hosts file didn't stick - did you make the change as root, and were there any issues with saving the file?

Comment: Oh ok. The debian server is installed on another computer on the same network and I was browsing from another computer. So in order for it to work, I would have to browse from the computer where debian is installed, correct? Yes, I made the change as root and there were no errors.

Comment: Either that or you need to add the /etc/hosts entry upon both the remote server _AND_ the server you're using the browser upon.

Comment: @Steve Kemp, thanks! Adding the /etc/hosts entry on both servers worked.